# How to create a new type of object based on a String?

Tags: java, class, oop, casting

first time posting here. Just starting to learn Java and coding in general, so please be patient with me!

So here I have a few classes. A Fruit class, with 2 subclasses - Orange and Watermelon.

```
public class Fruit {
    String name;
    String size;

    public Fruit() {
        this.name = "Fruit";
        this.size = "";
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public String getSize() {
        return this.size;
    }
}

class Orange extends Fruit {
    public Orange() {
        this.name = "Orange";
        this.size = "Small";
    }
}

class Watermelon extends Fruit {
    public Watermelon() {
        this.name = "Watermelon";
        this.size = "Large";
    }
}
```

I also have a Crate class, that I want to store Fruit Objects. However, I want it to store a particular object, based on what String is passed to the constructor.

```
public class Crate {
    Fruit f = new Fruit();

    public Crate(String fruitType) {
        if (fruitType == "Orange") {
            f = (Orange)f;
        } else {
            f = (Watermelon)f;
        }
    }

    public String getFruitName() {
        String s = f.getName();
        return s;
    }
}
```

Trying to downcast like this gives me an error. My question is how could I accomplish adding a certain Fruit subclass to the Crate object based on what is passed to the constructor?

EDIT: thank you everyone for the advice. Made the changes suggested and it works great!

Comment: Strings should be compared like this `if(fruitType.equals("Orange"))`, though other languages like `Javascript` and `C#` accept strings being compared with `==`  , `Java` does _not_ work the same way.

Comment: Your "factory" looks wrong to me a cast is not some kind of wizard that transmute objects

Comment: == tests for reference equality (whether they are the same object).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So many answers, all missing one **core** point:

Java is a **statically** typed language. Doing everything on **string** basis is **not** the way to go in Java. You try to **avoid** such code!

In other words: your first mistake is to create those different classes and carry around a "name" String. You could do something like:

```
abstract class Fruit {
  @Override
  public final String toString() {
    return getClass().getSimpleName() + getSize();
  }

  abstract String getSize();
```

instead. This will make sure that the string representation of **any** fruit simply gives the (short) class name (without package information) and whatever the subclasses implementation of `getSize()` returns.

You can use that like:

```
class Orange extends Fruit {
  private String size;
  Orange(String size) { this.size = size; };
  String getSize() { return size; }
```

For Oranges, that can have different sizes; but also

```
class Apple extends Fruit {
  String getSize() { return "always the same"; }
```

which in my examples are using the same size!

For creating objects, you rather go for a factory method, like:

```
Fruit createByName(String fruitName) {
  switch (fruitName) {
    case "Orange": return new Orange();
    case ...
    default: throw new IllegalArgumentException("unknown fruit: " + fruitName);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This clears some stuff up for me. My only other previous programming experience has been in Python, so I'm still getting used to the static typed language. Great explanation!

Comment: I am glad my thoughts were going into a helpful direction for you.

Answer (score 4):

The simplest way is to just see what's in the `String` and use `new`:

```
if ("Orange".equals(fruitType)) {
    f = new Orange();
} else if ("Watermelon".equals(fruitType)) {
    f = new Watermelon();
}
```

(You can also use a `switch` instead of `if...else if`.)

You could also pass in the `Fruit` to the constructor which makes things a whole lot simpler:

```
class Crate {
    Fruit fruit;

    Crate(Fruit fruitToHold) {
        this.fruit = fruitToHold;
    }
}
```

Some people will tell you that you can use reflection to create the `Fruit` and that's true but it's not really what you should be doing if you're a beginner.

Comment: You got my vote for the clear and precise wording; although my answer goes a bit in a different direction ... feedback would be welcome.

Comment: @GhostCat It's a good answer. I think you just posted it late. I think I got as many upvotes as I did just for suggesting to pass the `Fruit` in as an argument since it's a good style. OP's use of `String` makes me think that maybe they are taking input from `System.in`, so maybe the true answer is to use both a factory method like you suggested as well as pass the `Fruit` in to the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

You can't cast a class to something it is not. Since you called `new Fruit()`, it is only a fruit, so you can't cast to `Orange` or `Watermelon`.

Instead, you have to create the object of the appropriate type.

Also, you should never use `==` to compare `String` values. Always use `equals()`.

```
public class Crate {
    Fruit f;

    public Crate(String fruitType) {
        if (fruitType.equals("Orange")) {
            f = new Orange();
        } else {
            f = new Watermelon();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Casting does not change the type of the object!

You can only cast a variable to a type that the referenced object already is.

In your example the object in variable `fruitType` is of type `String`.
It is not related to `Fruit` `Orange` or `Watermellon` in any way. Therefore the cast fails.

What you can do is to create a *new* object of the desired type:

```
public Crate(String fruitType) {
    if (fruitType == "Orange") {
        f = new Orange();
    }
        else {
            f = new Watermelon();
    }
}
```

Problem is: you should not do something like this in a *constructor*. Also, comparing *Strings* with `==` is also a bad idea as the other answer and the comments suggest.

Comment: Thanks. Would a more appropriate path (rather than doing this in the constructor) be to create a method that adds the fruit?

Comment: @BrynM. The instatiation should be done in a *factory*. This is either a static method or a class of its own (depending on complexity). In your case the *static factory method* would be appropriate and its result should be passed as argument to the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

`==` tests for reference equality (whether they are the same object).

```
String s1="Orange";
String s2="Orange";
if(s1==s2) ===> true
```

**(s1==s2) ===> true**

```
                   String Pool
s1 -----------------> "Orange" <-----------------s2
```

**if(s1==s3) ===> false.**

```
            String Pool
"Orange" <-------------------- s1

               Heap
"Orange" <-------------------- s3
```

You need to use String `equals` method

```
if ("Orange".equals(fruitType)) {
    f = new Orange();
} else if ("Watermelon".equals(fruitType)) {
    f = new Watermelon();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The **==** operator doesn't work on comparing Strings because it is basically comparing the entire object including the memory position of it. That basically means that it will return tru only if both Strings being compared are basically the same instance. To compare 2 Strings in Java you can use the .equals(string2) method.

```
str1.equals(str2);
```

This compares only the value of the 2 Strings

Answer (score 0):

`"Orange" == "Orange"` this expression gives `true` if both of Strings points to the same memory location. That means both refer the same **String** object.

But `equal()` method will return after comparing the **values** of given objects.

Refer following examples,

```
"ss"=="ss"                       //true 
"ss" == new String("ss")         //false
"ss".equals("ss")                //true
"ss".equals(new String("ss"))    //true
```